# How to fix SPOService login issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0

Any body know why I'm getting this error

```
Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
At line:4 char:1
+ Connect-SPOService -Url https://companyname-admin.sharepoint.com -C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], IdcrlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell  
   .ConnectSPOService
```

even though I put in the correct username and password.

```
$username = "yzqpsn@company.com"
$password = "Example123$"

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $(convertto-securestring $password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-SPOService -Url https://company-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred
```

If I do only like this Connect-SPOService -Url https://company-admin.sharepoint.com then It prompt me to signin dialog box an I was able to connect using the same username and password I entered above.

I've already tried putting $ in a single quote and also backtick but still didn't work.
I was able to connect AzureAD and ExchangeOnline in the same script file using the same credential but not sure why I keep getting that error when I try to connect SPOService.

Comment: try using `$cred = get-credential`   .... You can verify if the password was stored properly by doing this ... `$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password`

Answer (score 2):

```
Connect-SPOService : The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.
```

There are two possible reasons for this error: either you have made a mistake while inserting your credentials, or you have a **multifactor authentication enabled (MFA)**. If it is due to the MFA, you will need to remove the **-Credential** parameter while connecting to SharePoint Online and enter your credentials with the traditional, login page experience.

According to your description, I think this is because you have enabled **multifactor authentication(MFA)**. Therefore, entering `Connect-SPOService -Url https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com` can connect to SharePoint normally, and entering `Connect-SPOService -Url https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $cred` will report an error.

**Reference:**

- [How to connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell?](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/connect-to-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/)